# How to write a test case if the provided content is there or not in vue.js by using jest?

Tags: vue.js, vue-test-utils, vue-jest

i have one component Register.vue which is responsible for registration , for this i am wrighting a test cases by using jest ,Here my doubt is How to write a test case for "Online Book Shopping" present in P-tag weather  content is matched or not,please help me to write a test case and for validations please share some reference for validating HTML REGEX pattern

`Register.vue`

```
<template>
<div class="main">
    <div class="container">
        <img id="side-img" src="../assets/sideImg.png" alt="notFound" />
<!-- i want to test weather this content is present or not -->
        <p id="side-content">Online Book Shopping</p> 
        <form>
           <div class="fullname">
           <p>FullName</p>
<!-- for this input tag correct pattern is passed or not -->
     <input type="name" class="namebox"  required v-model="fullName" pattern="[A-Za-z]{3,12}">
    </div>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</template>
```

`Register.spec.js`

```
import Register from '../../src/Pages/Register.vue';
import { createLocalVue, shallowMount} from '@vue/test-utils'
describe('Register.vue', ()=>{
    let wrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        const localVue = createLocalVue();
        wrapper = shallowMount(Register, localVue);
    });
    test('setup correctly', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true)
    })
    it('renders a vue instance', () => {
        expect(shallowMount(Register).isVueInstance()).toBe(true);
    })
    it('has an image', () => {
        expect(wrapper.contains('#side-img')).toBe(true);
    });
//  i stuck here weather the content is there or not 
    it('has online shopping content',()=>{
       except(wrapper.text()).toContain('Online Book Shopping');
    })
   
})
```

Comment: The test you pointed out is correctly verifying whether the text exists in the wrapper. Since the text is unconditionally rendered, that test should already pass. What's the problem?

Comment: I noticed a typo in your test: `except` should be `expect`.